# Information about "Warning: no DISPLAY variable so Tk is not available" in shinyapps.io logs

Tags: r, shiny, warnings, tk-toolkit, shinyapps

I have deployed my shinyapp online and I am constantly checking my logs for possible problems.
A warning message that often appears when some users connect to the platform is the following:

**Warning: no DISPLAY variable so Tk is not available**

and in general appears after the loading of the `proto` package, but I don't know if this is somehow related with the warning.

Do you have any idea of what this means and if it affects my application and hence some users cannot access to it? If yes, do I have to change something in my code or it depends to the user terminal?

Thanks a lot!